# Creating Extra Users From Carbon and Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, php-carbon

I'm trying to figure out why when I run this seed file it creates the 50 on the correct date however it still creates 4 more on the same day which it shouldn't. It should add 4 months from the original starting date and then start doing 5 users every 4 months. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
    $startingDate = Carbon::parse('First Monday of January 2010');
    $hiringDays = new DatePeriod(
        $startingDate->addMonths(4),
        CarbonInterval::months(4),
        Carbon::now()
    );

    $userCount = 1;
    for ($userCount; $userCount < 50; $userCount++) {
        factory(User::class)->create([
            'hired_at' => $startingDate,
        ]);
    }

    foreach ($hiringDays as $day)
    {
        for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
            factory(User::class)->create([
                'hired_at' => $day,
            ]);
            $this->userCount++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a while loop instead of DatePeriod

```
$hireDate = Carbon::parse('First Monday of January 2010');
$limit = $startingDate->copy()->addMonths(4);

while( $startingDate->lte( limit ) ){
    factory(User::class)->create([
        'hired_at' => $startingDate,
    ]);
    $this->userCount++;
    $startingDate->addMonth();
}
```